# Struts2 Localization with struts dojo autocompleter

Tags: java, struts2, autocomplete, localization

I have implemented autocomplete function using struts2 dojo autocompleter and I used localization for three languages. I have got some data from property files and the some data which I have got from backend to front end like list for drop down list, is not getting from other languages properties files when I change the language. It is always getting en_us (global.properties) file. Other data in Jsp file , which I have got from property file is coming properly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to comment without looking into your configurations and code.

But if you could validate your application against following detailed example you might be able to find any misconfigurations or code issues.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_localization.htm

Comment: Hi Thamilvaanan,  I checked that and the issue is Localization is working fine for the stuff in JSP only. But the thing is <sx:autocompleter key="global.selectRoad" 
   list="roads" name="roadsInColombo" resultsLimit="-1" dropdownHeight="300" dropdownWidth="300" cssStyle="width: 300px"/>   here only the roads list is not changing.

Comment: that roads list is coming from back end and always it's showing the locale is en_us.

Comment: @user2706146 You need the back end data to be converted to the different locals?

Comment: @user2706146 You need the back end data to be converted to the different locals? probably you have to check the how you populate the list "roads"

Comment: I'm generating this roads list from the constructor which is in Action class. Like,  String roads = getText("global.roads");  I'm getting this roads list from the property file and split from comma and add to roads list. But always It's coming global.properties file. It means not taking other languages. but the values in Jsp is getting change. I'm stuck in there. Please help.

Comment: You are passing request_local to action and also using "<interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>" in your stack right? can you try to debug and find the whether your local is set properly at action class?

Comment: Hi Thamilvaanan, I found the issue. I always loaded the roads list in constructor. So initially It was default locale each time en_us. Then I load the data again in the method of locale action and then It was correctly loading the data. Thanks a lot for your support and I have lost my valuable time for small mistake. Thanks again.